# Do Podcasts belong under the "Articles and Blogs" section

Tags: discussion, jobs

I listed some podcasts under the "Articles and Blogs" section in my profile and I think it would be nice to make it more obvious that this is something employers would be interested in.

As an employer, I think that knowing that a developer listens to certain podcasts helps paint a picture of what the developer is learning and that they are at least attempting to stay current.

I get a lot of information on new technology via listening to podcasts and it is a great way to make time spent commuting more productive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s the right category. We hadn’t considered podcasts specifically, so we’ll look at updating the header.